# Why the Text retains in input field even I clear that field and send new keys using selenium WebDriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[here is my HTML AND web App] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHfgC.png)
Here is my Code:

```
@Test(priority = 9)
    public void EditCompositeLevel() throws InterruptedException  {

        // Wait for the 'Name' input field to be present and clear its content
     WebElement nameInput=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text' and @placeholder='Name']"));

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        nameInput.clear();
      
        Thread.sleep(3000);
     System.out.println( driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@placeholder='Name'])[1]")).getText()
       ) ; 
     
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println( driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@placeholder='Name'])[1]")).getText());
    }
```

I tried to clear the input field using webobject object.clear();
then i want to send input value using webobject object.sendkeys.  but it retains previous input value before i send keys